# Does XAML has a version?

Tags: wpf, xaml, xaml-2009

WPF 4.0 is a buzzword these days which is the latest version of WPF, I want to know what is the current version of XAML? And, what was the previous version of XAML as well as WPF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rob Relyea of the XAML team](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/default.aspx) has referred to the XAML implementation in .NET 4 as "XAML 2009" (e.g. [here](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/archive/2009/06/01/xaml-using-generic-types-in-xaml-2009.aspx)).  I don't think XAML in .NET 3.x had a version -- everyone just called it XAML (and it had two implementations, one for WPF and one for WF).

However I understand that in .NET 4.0 WPF will still be using its own XAML implementation for most things, rather than moving wholesale to the new common XAML implementation.

**EDIT:** Added citation supplied by [Kent Boogaart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5380/kent-boogaart).

Comment: +1 Referred to as "XAML 2009" on Rob's blog here: http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/archive/2009/06/01/xaml-using-generic-types-in-xaml-2009.aspx

Comment: The first generation is sometimes referred to as **XAML2006**.

Answer (score 1):

One might expect the version of XAML to be encoded in the namespace, however both VS 2008 and VS 2010 Beta 2 apply the same namespaces to XAML files:

```
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

A loose xaml file reader would have no way of knowing which version of xaml was targeted.

In VS 2010 Beta 2 you can choose to target WPF 3.0, WPF 3.5 or WPF 4.0.

It appears that the same version of XAML may work for all the different versions of WPF as long as the object types encoded are present in that version.